# Mysql dump restore delete data if it has FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS settings

Tags: mysql, database, docker, foreign-keys

I have `db_dump.sql`

```
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 

10.1.23-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: school
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.1.23-MariaDB

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `school`
--

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `school` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */;

USE `school`;

--
-- Table structure for table `student`
--

/*!40101 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student` */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `studentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `classID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `_createdTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `_deletedTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `_lastUpdateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_idx` (`studentID`,`classID`),
  KEY `fk_student_classID` (`classID`),
  KEY `k_id_studentID_studentName` (`id`,`studentID`,`name`),
  KEY `idx_clid_csid_clnm` (`studentID`,`classID`,`name`),
  KEY `idx_csid_clid_clnm` (`classID`,`studentID`,`name`),
  KEY `idx_clnm` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_csid_clnm` (`classID`,`name`),
  KEY `idx_clnm_csid` (`name`,`classID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_student_classID` FOREIGN KEY (`classID`) REFERENCES `class` (`classID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20741715 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


--
-- Table structure for table `class`
--

/*!40101 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `class` */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class` (
  `classID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `className` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `_createdTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `_lastUpdateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `_deletedTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classID`),
  KEY `className` (`className`),
  KEY `idx_csid_csname` (`classID`,`className`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'school'
--
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cleanupDDBStats` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cleanupDDBStats`(numDaysOld INT)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

        SET @t1 = unix_timestamp(now() - INTERVAL numDaysOld DAY);


        DELETE
        FROM    ddbStats
        WHERE   modifiedTime < @t1;

        COMMIT;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2019-10-03 19:58:32
```

I have `docker-compose.yml` as

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  galera-data:

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: chagridsada/galera-mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "galera-data:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      CLUSTER_NAME: galera-db-cluster
      CLUSTER_JOIN:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dev
      XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD: dev
```

I created docker container using `docker-compose up -d`

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "training_default" with the default driver
Creating mysql ... done
```

Dump the database to newly created container and inserted the data.

```
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev' < db_dump.sql
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev -e "show databases;"'
Database
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
school

$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "select * from class;"'
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "select * from student;"'

$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "insert into class (classID, className) values (1, \"test\");"'
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "select * from class;"'
classID className   _createdTime    _lastUpdateTime _deletedTime
1   test    2019-11-20 15:25:00 2019-11-20 15:25:00 NULL

$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "insert into student (classID, studentID, name) values (1, 1, \"test\");"'
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "select * from student;"'
id  studentID   classID name    _createdTime    _deletedTime    _lastUpdateTime
20741715    1   1   test    2019-11-20 15:26:01 NULL    2019-11-20 15:26:01
```

Now if I dump the data again, which has `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` means, don't create a table if it exists, but still its `creating` table or simply delete the data.

```
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev' < db_dump.sql
$ docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev school -e "select * from student;"'
```

I did some try and error and find out if I remove `/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;` from the dump, its not deleting the data.

This problem occurs when we have `child` table (**student**) before `parent` table (**class**) in our `db_dump.sql`.

Logically, this dump file set the `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` before it starts, and set it back at the end `/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;`, but somehow, still it delete the records.

Why it delete record when run dump again ?

```
docker exec -i mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -pdev' < db_dump.sql
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the status report. Was there a *question* ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland updated the question, I am looking, why its delete the record?

Comment: @spencer7593 updated the question

Comment: Maybe the observed behavior can be explained by these two statements: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student` and `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS class`

Comment: yes, but its commented, and even if we consider it, why that not get effect when I remove `/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;` ? If I remove this line, then record stays after dump again.

Comment: Are you aware of MySQL's special comment syntax `/*! ... */`? The statement will run, even though it seems to be in a comment. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html

Comment: I'm guessing when you remove the lines about foreign key checks, you also removed the lines about DROP TABLE.

Comment: No, `DROP TABLE` is still there,

Comment: Then the DROP TABLE will run, even though you think it's in a comment.

Comment: Note that the execution of the `DROP TABLE` statement will *fail* if there are foreign key constraints that reference the table,  unless we disable enforcement of foreign key constraints, which we can do by setting the `foreign_key_checks` system variable to `0`. That's the reason the sql script sets that system variable to 0.  So that the DROP TABLE statement will not fail due to a foreign key constraint.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks, removing `DROP TABLE` works and It not delete the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
/*!40101 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student` */;
```

The script is not re-creating the database indeed, but it is re-creating each table.

Comment: yes, but why its not re-creating if I remove `/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;` ?

Comment: @Nilesh:  The setting of `foreign_key_checks` system variable determines whether foreign key constraints are enabled or disabled. Setting it to 0 disables enforcement of foreign key constraints, and that allows the DROP TABLE statement to succeed. Otherwise, if foreign key constraints are enabled, the `DROP TABLE` statement will fail (if there are any foreign key constraints that reference the table.)